# Call Function outside if the class PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I want to execute the nextstep() function in the Window class, but outside the class. 
The function is called on window.nextstep() but the label text is not set. 
Error message:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>.
  File "D:\python\mcmods\mcmods\src\guitools.py", line 56, in setupApp
    window.nextstep()
  File "D:\python\mcmods\mcmods\src\guitools.py", line 39, in nextstep
    self.label.setText("Konfigurationen werden erstellt")
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'label'.
```

Here ist the code:

```
def setupApp():
    class Window(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setFixedSize(320,250)
            self.setWindowTitle("Wird geladen...")

            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
            #self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
            prog_bar = QProgressBar(self)
            prog_bar.setGeometry(50, 100, 250, 30)
            prog_bar.setValue(0)
            label = QLabel("X wird gestartet...", self)
            label.setGeometry(90, 100, 250, 30)

        def nextstep(self):
            if os.path.exists(str(Path.home) + "\mcmods") == False:
                appdata = AppDataPaths("mcmods")
                appdata.setup()
                adpath = str(appdata.app_data_path)
                self.label.setText("Konfigurationen werden erstellt")
                os.system('mkdir "' + adpath + '"')
                sleep(1)
                newconfig = open(adpath + "\config.json", "w+")
                sleep(1)
                newconfig.write(str('''{
                    "version": "''' + VERSION + '''",
                    "DataFolder": "''' + adpath + "\mcmods\\" + '''",
                    "allowModImport": false
                    }'''))
                newconfig.close()
```

Comment: please post your code and error messages directly into the body of your question...

Comment: Did you mean: `self.label = QLabel("X wird  ...`?

Comment: @quamrana  I corrected that in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include where you execute the `nextstep` method, but either way I would suggest removing the function that encapsulates the `Window` class and making the window a top level class.  Then you would  need to initialize a `Window` class instance before you can run `window.nextstep()`.  It is also required that a `QApplication` instance must be initialized as well.

For example.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(320,250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Wird geladen...")

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        prog_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        prog_bar.setGeometry(50, 100, 250, 30)
        prog_bar.setValue(0)
        self.label = QLabel("X wird gestartet...", self)  # self.label
        self.label.setGeometry(90, 100, 250, 30)          # self.label

    def nextstep(self):
        if os.path.exists(str(Path.home) + "\mcmods") == False:
            appdata = AppDataPaths("mcmods")
            appdata.setup()
            adpath = str(appdata.app_data_path)
            self.label.setText("Konfigurationen werden erstellt")
            os.system('mkdir "' + adpath + '"')
            sleep(1)
            newconfig = open(adpath + "\config.json", "w+")
            sleep(1)
            newconfig.write(str('''{
                "version": "''' + VERSION + '''",
                "DataFolder": "''' + adpath + "\mcmods\\" + '''",
                "allowModImport": false
                }'''))
            newconfig.close()

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.nextstep()
app.exec()
```

Comment: @GoodKing Please write comments in English.

Comment: @GoodKing  try it now... I fixed the problem

Comment: @GoodKing Then, if now it works and it solved your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left. Please take your time to follow the [tour]. And remember what said before: comments should ***always*** be in English, even if they are directly intended for a specific user that you know speaks another language: others might find your comment useful (maybe they're following the post and are experiencing the same problem as you are), or could directly answer you before the other user could.